# rebuild torch tensor from its batchified version

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, feature-extraction, torch

This is very nice example of how to build a 3D tensor:

```
import torch
y = torch.rand(100, 1)
batch_size = 10
batched_data = y.contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, y.size(-1)).transpose(0,1)
batched_data.shape
```

the output is:

```
torch.Size([10, 10, 1])
```

ok, now what I want to do is, starting from batched_data I want to build y.
The other way around.
Any good suggestion with a powerful pytorch streamlined code?

==== Additional input =====

I am using this for RNN and now I have some doubts, becaus eif you consider the following code:

```
import torch
y = torch.arange(100).view(100,1)
batch_size = 10
batched_data = y.contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, y.size(-1)).transpose(0,1)
batched_data.shape
```

The output is:

```
tensor([[[ 0],
         [10],
         [20],
         [30],
         [40],
         [50],
         [60],
         [70],
         [80],
         [90]],

        [[ 1],
         [11],
         [21],
         [31],
         [41],
         [51],
         [61],
         [71],
         [81],
         [91]],
```

Which I would not expect. I would expect something like: 
`[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],....`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to do something like this to rebuild y:

```
rebuilded_y = batched_data.transpose(0,1).view(*y.shape)
```

To make the input look like you expected you need to remove transpose and additional dimension in batched_data:

```
batched_data = y.contiguous().view(batch_size, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it is correct, but what do you think of additional comments I put in my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prepare inputs for RNN, you need to know that [RNN](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=rnn#torch.nn.RNN) takes 3d tensors of shape, `seq_len, batch, input_size`. Here, `input_size` refers to the number of features and in your scenario, it is 1. So, the input tensor of shape `10, 10, 1` can still be a valid input for an RNN.

**Example**

```
rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=1, hidden_size=20, num_layers=1)
input = torch.randn(10, 10, 1)
output, hn = rnn(input)
print(output.size()) # 10, 10, 20
```

RNN's output is of shape, `seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size`.